# Rosh hashanah chassidut simcha

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, simchah-joy-happiness, tzadok-hakohen-lublin

Does anyone know where i could find a rav tzadok that elaborates on the simcha of rosh hashanah by the pesukim in nechemia

Comment: On a side note, I've heard Rav Elimelech Biderman quotes the Shagas Aryeh (Siman 102), who also mentions the simcha of Rosh Hashanah.